# Data types in struct when reverse engineering

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering

In the book Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering on pg 152 he is working through reversing some Windows API and we have figured out that the struct looks like this

```
struct TABLE
{
UNKNOWN Member1;
UNKNOWN_PTR Member2;
UNKNOWN_PTR Member3;
UNKNOWN_PTR Member4;
UNKNOWN Member5;
UNKNOWN Member6;
UNKNOWN Member7;
UNKNOWN Member8;
UNKNOWN Member9;
UNKNOWN Member10;
};
```

I followed how he got to this point, and then he looks at another function in the API and provides this bit

> Let’s proceed to investigate what is hopefully a simple function: RtlNumberGenericTableElements. The idea is that if the root data structure has a
>   member that represents the total number of elements in the table, this function
>   would expose it. If not, this function would iterate through all the elements
>   and just count them while doing that. The following is the OllyDbg output for
>   RtlNumberGenericTableElements.

```
RtlNumberGenericTableElements:
7C923FD2 PUSH EBP
7C923FD3 MOV EBP,ESP
7C923FD5 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [EBP+8]
7C923FD8 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [EAX+14]
7C923FDB POP EBP
7C923FDC RET 4
```

> Well, it seems that the question has been answered. This function simply
>   takes a pointer to what one can only assume is the same structure as before,
>   and returns whatever is in offset +14. Clearly, offset +14 contains the number
>   of elements in a generic table data structure. Let’s update the definition of the TABLE structure.

with only that function returning the number of elements in the table, he updates the structure to how it is below.

```
struct TABLE
{
UNKNOWN     Member1;
UNKNOWN_PTR Member2;
UNKNOWN_PTR Member3;
UNKNOWN_PTR Member4;
UNKNOWN     Member5;
ULONG       NumberOfElements;
UNKNOWN     Member7;
UNKNOWN     Member8;
UNKNOWN     Member9;
UNKNOWN     Member10;
};
```

Notice all he does is update Member6 to be of type ULONG and call it NumberOfElements, obviously the member contains some sort of int to contain the number of elements of the table, but how does he know from this that it is a ULONG? could it not also be a UINT or INT or is he just making some assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Since this is about 32-bit, `ULONG` is the same as `UINT`. And it has to be unsigned because it's about the size/amount of something, which can't be negative.

Note that many other structures and functions use `DWORD` for such values (number of element, etc.), but it's also defined as unsigned integer just like `ULONG` and `UINT` - their differences in usage are historical (16-bit era, etc.).